# mysql_insert_id() returning '0'

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I have a query that runs properly, it inserts a row into a table which has a primary key that auto increses. But the mysql_insert_id() always comes out as '0'.

```
$this->event->insertEvent($event);
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();
```

I've used the same command in another area of the site, and it's worked perfectly. 
What could be the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Docs say `The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.`  Are you running another query inside that function that overrides the last insert id result?

Comment: Can you show the method where you run your insert? It might be related.

Comment: From design point of view it would be more clear so that your `insertEvent()` returned the id for you

Comment: I'm working off of someone else's base code. I can confirm that the insertEvent is populating the database, as well as populating the auto-increase field with the latest number. As I insert more fields, the auto-increasement is rising as it should. Also, there is only one database in this project.

Comment: I was able to get the insertEvent() to return the value properly now. Thanks Zerkms for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the PHP pages and possibly something you can do to rule out one more thing if it doesn't fix it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php#94511

> If mysql_insert_id() returns 0 or null, check that you have also
>   included the link identifier. It is optional but if you have more than
>   one database connection then this is necessary.
>
> ex: mysql_insert_id($conn)

Comment: Is it necessary when there is only one database?

Comment: You can have more then one connection to one database. mysql_insert_id() without parameters would be use last connection, but INSERT query may be performed from another, so mysql_insert_id() will return 0